# How can i formay List<DateTime> items to List<string> items and format the items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Class in top of class file

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Explode<T>(this T value, Func<T, T> next, Func<T, bool> limit)
    {
        yield return value;
        var n = next(value);
        while (!limit(n))
        {
            yield return n;
            n = next(n);
        }
    }
```

In constructor

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2016, 06, 24, 22, 00, 00);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2016, 06, 25, 13, 10, 00);
var result = a.Explode(x => x.AddMinutes(10), x => x > b).ToList();
```

The first item in the List result is:

[0] = {6/24/2016 10:00:00 PM}

Second item

[1] = {6/24/2016 10:10:00 PM}

Now i want to format each item to this format for example the first item:

20160624_2200

And if the item in List result is AM like: [2] = {6/24/2016 10:10:00 AM}
Then the new format should be:

20160624_1010

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `.Select(d => d.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` has an overload of `ToString()` that allows special formats. Your's would be this:

```
var result = a.Explode(x => x.AddMinutes(10), x => x > b)
    .Select(d => d.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")).ToList();
```